# Extend a Class that conforms a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

How can I make an extension of a class that implements a protocol ?

Something like that :

```
protocol proto {
    func hey()
}
```

and a class that conforms to `proto` :

```
Class MyClass: UIViewController, proto {
     func hey() {
         print("Hey!")
     }
}
```

and then an extension of that class that would look like :

```
extension UIViewController where Self:proto {
     func test() {
         print("I'm extended!")
     }
}
```

So that I can call `self.test()` in `MyClass`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just extend protocol, not the type. Please, try the following:

```
protocol proto {
    func hey()
}

class MyClass: UIViewController, proto {
    func hey() {
        print("Hey!")
    }

    func test2() {
        self.test()
    }
}

extension proto where Self: UIViewController {
    func test() {
        print("I'm extended!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to declare `test` method in `proto` so that `MyClass` knows it implements this method.

```
protocol proto {
    func hey()
    func test()
}
```

Also you have to "reverse" the statements in the protocol extension:

```
extension proto where Self : UIViewController {
    func test() {
        print("I'm extended!")
    }
}
```

After that, `MyClass` is magically extended and you can call `test` method on it:

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, proto {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        test()
    }
}
```